# Creating a histogram to display how many items are in each category/bin with stars

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, histogram

With the following test values, I need my program to output this histogram.

Values: 30, 40, 45, 102, 35, 42, 65, 89, 55, 48, 56, 46, 42, 54, 56, 51, 47, 50, 51, 50, 50, 47, 52, 53, 47, 44, 69, 35, 40, 45, 35, 42, 65, 55, 48, 100, 56, 46, 42, 54, 56, 51, 47, 50, 51, 50, 50, 47, 52, 53, 47, 78, 80, and 95

```
Histogram: 
 9| ***
 8| **
 7| *
 6| ***
 5| **********************
 4| *******************
 3| ****
 2|
 1|
 0|
SD: 15.2579
```

This program needs to also find the standard deviation of the values entered, as well as the mean. The instructions asks for four different functions to be in the program:
main, mean, deviation, and histogram.
Only iomanip and iostream can be used as well as header files such as , and no global variables are allowed.

Here are the full assignment instructions:

Use only iostream and iomanip functions for I/O and formatting (no stdio) - but may use other header files such as 
Your program will have four functions:
main
mean
deviation
histogram

**main**

Define a variable to mantain a count of the number of scores entered and initialize it to 0

Define the scores array (the scores array does not need to be initialized)

Allow for a maximum (not total) of 100 scores

Read a list of integers from the console one at a time and place each integer into the scores array

None of the entered scores will be < 0

Increment count for each score read and stored in the scores array

Stop the data entry and begin the calculations when the user enters a -1 (do not include the -1 in the data)

Call the histogram function (pass any arguments that are needed)

Print the histogram (the histogram function fills and returns the bins array but you must print the histogram in main

Call the deviation function, which returns the standard deviation
Print the standard deviation (steps j and k may be combined into a single statement if desired)

**mean**

Pass in whatever arguments are needed

Return a double value that is the mean or average of the scores

**deviation**

Pass in whatever arguments you need

Return a double that is the standard deviation of the scores

**histogram** (the histogram function fills and returns the bins array - it does NOT print the histogram)

Calculate the histogram (i.e., fill but do not print the bins array)

Returning an array from a function presents a special problem. The text presents the problem and three possible solutions.

Each element in the bins array is really an accumulator and so must be initialized to 0.

Group the scores in the histogram as follows:

```
Bin 9: score ≥ 90
Bin 8: score ≥ 80 but < 90
Bin 7: score ≥ 70 but < 80
    .
    .
    .
Bin 1: score ≥ 10 but < 20
Bin 0: score < 10
```

Note that some scores in the input include extra credit (i.e., are > 100); your program must work for scores up to 109.

**Here is my code so far**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double mean(double array[], int count);
double SD(double array[], int count);
void histogram(double array[], int count, int* bin);

int main()
{
int count = 0;
double array[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    array[i] = 100;
}

int bin[10]{};
for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
{
    bin[b] = 0;
}

while (true)
{
    double score;
    cout << "Please enter scores (-1 to end): ";
    cin >> score;
    if (score != -1)
        array[count++] = score;
    else
        break;
}

cout << "Mean = " << mean(array, count) << endl;
cout << "SD = " << SD(array, count) << endl;
cout << "Count = " << count << endl;
cout << bin;

}

double mean(double array[], int count)
{
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    sum += array[i];

double mean = sum / count;
return mean;
}   

double SD(double array[], int count)
{
double SD = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    SD += pow(array[i] - mean(array, count), 2);
return sqrt(SD / count);
}

void histogram(double array[], int count, int* bin)
{
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int Bin = array[i] / 10;
    if (Bin > 9)
        Bin = 9;
    bin[Bin]++;
}

}
```

I think I've got the mean and standard deviation functions setup well, but I could use some guidance with the other two functions (histogram and main). My question right now is, how should I assign values from the array to bin categories? Thanks!

Comment: if you use a `std::map`, the code for histogramming is 2-3 lines (no exaggeration). Your question is a bit vague. Try to ask a more specific question. Maybe this can help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: I'll look into that. I'll edit my question as well, thank you!

Comment: Without running looks OK. IF you are after a code review their is a site dedicated to that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The one thing I note is: `the histogram function fills and returns the bins array - it **does NOT** print the histogram` your code does print the results. Should probably move that.

Comment: The arrays are not initialized. `double array[100]; int bin[10];`. Without initialization these values are indeterminate and reading them is not valid (therefore incrementing this not valid as an increment requires a read). Not a big deal fro `array` but `bin` this is an issue.

Comment: I'll move that, thanks.

Comment: That makes sense,  I edited my code. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The code is close to what needed, but not there yet.

To initialize `bin`, a simple

```
int bin[10] {};
```

Is enough. Note that the posted code initializes every element of the array to `10` instead, probably a typo.

You have to change the prototype and the definition of `histogram` too, due to a type mismatch:

```
void histogram(double array[], int count, int* bin) {
//             ^^^^^^
```

I'll not write the code that actually prints the histograms, but, given the constraints, you might want to look at [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [std::setfill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill).

Comment: I went ahead and made those edits you suggested, and they make more sense to me now. I also checked out std::setw and std::setfill, and they look like just what I need. I'm curious how I could go about implementing those into my code, seeing that the setw() value will be dependent upon what the user inputs.

Comment: @Cbiscuit I didn't notice, but you just have to look closely at the examples in the linked pages.